# compare jsoup elements

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsoup

hello guys i am try to compare one jsoup element with all other elements and if two elements are equal i need to make count++; in this case i need to compare all elements in links1 with all elements in links2 links3 links4....

```
Document document1 = Jsoup.parse(webPage1);
Elements links1 = document1.select("example");

Document document2 = Jsoup.parse(webPage2);
Elements links2 = document2.select("example");

Document document3 = Jsoup.parse(webPage3);
Elements links3 = document3.select("example");

Document document4 = Jsoup.parse(webPage4);
Elements links4 = document4.select("example");
```

what would be the code....in JSP....

Answer (score 0):

`Elements` is just a List of `Element`, so compating will look like:

```
   for (Element element : links1) {
            if(links2.contains(element)){
                count++;
            }
            //maybe do the same thing with links3 links4.
        }
```

If you want do it in JSP — this is another question.